# Run RMI Hello world in Mac OS X Lion Failed

Tags: java, osx-lion, rmi

I've been trying to execute the commands to run the RMI Hello world example but I Failed!

My execution steps are taken from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/hello/hello-world.html

The commands are:

- `javac`: works fine and I get the class files
- `rmiregistry &`: I get something like `[1] 17122`
- `java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/users/ha/RMI/ example.hello.Server`:

Gives me an error message

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   example/hello/Server Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   example.hello.Server  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Comment: I used to edit the class path in windows, but here in mac I didn't do that, is it necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did solve this problem by running each command on a new terminal window.
First I started with javac for the .java files, then run the command rmiregistry &.

Second I opened a new terminal window and run the command java for the Server class.

Third I opened a new terminal window and run the command java for the Client class.

and it works with me!

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac, the Users directory in the root directory is written with a capital letter.

You wrote:

> file:/**users**/ha/RMI/

file:/**Users**/ha/RMI/ would be correct. **This applies only to file systems that have been setup explicitly to setup to ignore case (Case-insensitive). At least that is what the comments below are saying. I cannot verify this myself.**

A classpath is also needed under many circumstances. It depends on your dependencies. But if you needed the classpath in windows, you will need a similar one on Mac.

Depending on where you .class files are, I would add the classpath to your invocation.

```
java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/users/ha/RMI/ -cp=/Users/ha/RMI example.hello.Server
```

This assumes, of course, that the class files are under /Users/ha/RMI/example/hello

Just look inside of the directory to verify that the class files are there. It should be the directory that you designated after the javac command and -d argument.

Comment: MacOS file system is case insensitive so should not matter

Comment: edit it to: java -classpath /Users/ha/RMI/ -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/Users/ha/RMI/ example.hello.Server, but still getting the same error message

Comment: My MacOS file system was set intentionally to case sensitive. Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, journaled). This is a much more reliable setting for iPhone Development. For XIB files using ~ipad or ~iPad (or ~iphone/~iPhone) you wouldn't have a problem in the simulator, but the device will show the wrong results in one of the cases (iPad won't work on a device). It is a valid statement to verify that this isn't a problem first.

Comment: The problem should be your classpath then.

Comment: Make sure you are targeting the directory where the class files are living and not the java files.

Comment: @Terry Dye how can I do that in mac?

Comment: If you're using Terminal, you can just use the 'ls'-Command. For example: ls /Users/ha/RMI/example/hello Or go to your Finder and look in the directory. I would look in /Users/ha/RMI/example/hello directory.

Comment: @Evanescence did the last comment help you? Have you had success with your tests?

Comment: @Terry Dye Thanx for asking, yes I did.

Answer (score 0):

I used three terminal windows for execution of a rmiregistry program.

1.Use this terminal window to compile all your files (javac filename.java) and use the command "rmiregistry &" this is the windows equivalent command for "start rmiregistry". (Note:'start' command doesn't work on the macOS)

2.Use this to run the java file ie. Server file (ie. java RMI_Server)

3.Use this to run the client file ie. Client file (ie. java RMI_Client 127.0.0.1)

And yeah it worked for me. (Note: The Directory should be set properly in the terminal)